# Prevent flex items in the last row becoming larger than other flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flex container and flex items defined as follows:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;   
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;     
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;  
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
  <li class="flex-item">10</li>
  <li class="flex-item">11</li>
  <li class="flex-item">12</li>
  <li class="flex-item">13</li>
  <li class="flex-item">14</li>
</ul>
```

If there are few items in the last row, they get streched and have larger width than the items in the upper rows.

[image: current behaviour]

As you can see in the image, box 13 and 14 have larger width.

Is it possible to make the items in the last row of the same size as the items in upper rows ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding invisible flex items is the most popular way to go. It keeps all the flex good stuff and is a hack that makes clear sense.

```
.hidden-flex-item {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    padding: 5px;     
    margin-top: 10px;  
    margin-right: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/px37t2jc/9/

Css grid can also handle this sort of issue easily if you take the time to learn it.

Comment: I used css grid as you had suggested and solved the issue.

Comment: Very nice. thank you.

Comment: Grid is pretty complex and has beneath its benefits some downsides compared to flexbox (mainly because it is pretty "rigid") … Your answer hints in the right direction but is a bit unclear. The solution is to give the flex items a defined width with e.g. `flex-basis: 33.33%` and `flex-grow: 0`. Then you can add a spacer-flex-item at the end with `::after` that has `flex-grow: 1` to take the remaining space.

Comment: @GDY Grid is pretty straightforward to learn actually. There is definitely pros and cons. Flexbox is for linear styling and grid is good for layouts. Personally I prefer adding an invisible box instead of `::after`. It's more intuitive to understand.

Answer (score 6):

If you know what the widths are of boxes 1-12 (if there's a set width you'd like, or just inspect with chrome dev tools and get the width), then set a `max-width: *px;` to the `flex-item` CSS.

Here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVgKMV

[image]